# give a custom class a standard type but the possibility to add other types

Tags: ios, swift, class, types

I have a protocol (EasyPosTypes), which contains all types that should be able to get asigned to the variables.

```
protocol EasyPosTypes { }
protocol EasyPosStandardTypes { }

extension EPPercentage: EasyPosTypes { }
extension Int: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes { }
extension CGFloat: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes { }
extension Double: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes { }
extension Float: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes { }
```

Then I have the Variables, x and y should be able to be the types defined above (EasyPosTypes):

```
struct FrameComponent {
    var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    var height: CGFloat = 0.0

    var x: EasyPosTypes = 0.0
    var y: EasyPosTypes = 0.0
    var percentX: CGFloat = -1
    var percentY: CGFloat = -1
}

protocol EasyPos {
    var fc: FrameComponent { get set }
    func update()
}
```

And here I want to test for the Types. For all except for EPPercent I want to run the code in the if statement and for EPPercent I want to run the on in the else if:

```
extension EasyPos where Self: UIView {
    func update() {
        if let xFloat = fc.x as? EasyPosStandardTypes {
            frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(xFloat), y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        } else if let xPercent = fc.x as? EPPercent {
            frame = CGRect(x: fc.screenWidth * CGFloat(xPercent) - frame.width / 2, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the if gives the following error:

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(EasyPosStandardTypes)'"

The code in the else:

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(EPPercent)'"

Comment: Don't you want to use typealias instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your protocols adding `asCGFloat` calculated property

```
protocol EasyPosStandardTypes {
    var asCGFloat:  CGFloat { get }
}

extension Int: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes {
    var asCGFloat:  CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}
extension CGFloat: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes {
    var asCGFloat:  CGFloat { return self }
}
extension Double: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes {
    var asCGFloat:  CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}
extension Float: EasyPosTypes, EasyPosStandardTypes {
    var asCGFloat:  CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}
```

And after that, you can use this new property when you need to get a `CGFloat` value from types which conform `EasyPosStandardTypes` protocol.

```
if let xFloat = fc.x as? EasyPosStandardTypes {
    frame = CGRect(x: xFloat.asCGFloat, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
} // ...
```